# why bootstrap tool-tip is not initializing two times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
 </div>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();  
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').off("mouseenter mouseleave");
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

 });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

why i am not able to get tooltip even if i initializing two times ??

Comment: The tooltip component is part of jQueryUI not jQuery. You have to import jQueryUI too: http://code.jquery.com/ui/

Comment: @Sebastian No, tooltip is part of Bootstrap here.

Comment: @DavidG My bad, sorry. I've tried your code Mahi and it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/R3l4x3/jbkocd0p/
Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: @Sebastian its working for the first time but when i remove event using jquery off and initialize 2nd time why tooltip is not working ??

Comment: Try adding a `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('destroy');` before you re-initialise.

Comment: @DavidG thanks but why is it ??

Comment: Removing the listener's does not destroy the tooltip, it only leaves the existing tooltip mangled missing it's functionality. Calling `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` a second time is basically a noop, the tooltip has already been initialized on those elements and it won't do it again. Take a look at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/js/src/tooltip.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DavidG's comment with logging. Basically you need to completely destroy the `tooltip` if you want to be able to call `tooltip` again and have it attach the listeners. By doing calling `off` you were just removing the listeners but not destroying the `tooltip`. Therefore when you called `tooltip` a second time it would not initialize the `tooltip` again. Because of the following line:

```
if (!data) $this.data('bs.tooltip', (data = new Tooltip(this, options)))
```

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/js/tooltip.js#L501

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
 </div>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log("init");
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log("destroy");
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("destroy");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log("reinit");
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                }, 5000);
            }, 5000);
 });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but in my project tooltip('destroy') is not working . :(

Comment: @Mahi what version of bootstrap are you using? it was changed to `dispose` in version 4.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the duplicate declaration and added a tooltip placement and now it works

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
 </div>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
 });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no that's not what i wanted . .. why it is not working if i am initializing two times ??

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why it doesn't work if you initialise it twice, but I know that it's not good practice and can break things. Why do you want to initialise it twice?

Comment: Actually, I just re-tried it. It works perfectly if you initialise it twice. The problem was the lack of the ```data-placement``` tag.

Comment: it's a big code and after removing event using jquery off tooltip was not working so had to initialize two times .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a id="anchor" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
 </div>

 <script>
    var handler = function (e) {
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();  
    }
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').off("mouseenter mouseleave",handler);
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on("mouseenter mouseleave",handler);
 });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

It works, though I believe there might be better solutions if you elaborate more on what exactly it is that you want to do.